# Warning message when pooling analysis from coxph after using mice in R: large sample assumed

Tags: r, warnings, r-mice

I get the following warning when pooling results in `mice`:

```
Warning message:
In mice.df(m, lambda, dfcom, method) : Large sample assumed.
```

This is the same question as can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128838/mice-pool-function-and-coxph-in-mice-df-large-sample-assumend). However I have done some reading and found some sources which may help solve the issue, hence the new question.

I have found the code and function that generates this warning: https://github.com/stefvanbuuren/mice/blob/master/R/mice.df.r This indicates the message is displayed when `dfcom`, from the function `mice.df`, is < 99999.

The documentation about the internal function `mice.df` is contained here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mice/versions/2.14/topics/mice.internal

However I can see no mention of `dfcom`.

The warning message also appears in this example, done by Stef Van Buuren, but they seem to completely ignore it: https://gerkovink.github.io/miceVignettes/Sensitivity_analysis/Sensitivity_analysis.html

A reproducible example can be found on the the previously referenced stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128838/mice-pool-function-and-coxph-in-mice-df-large-sample-assumend)

I would like to know:

A) What is this warning?

B) Should I be concered about the warning? (Should follow on from Q1)

C) Is this question more relevant to stackoverflow, or stackexchange?